# My RecyclerView is laggy

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

im using RecyclerView - CardView And volley to get mysql item with json and show in my application , in every cardview row i have one vertical layout and in this layout i have 4 horizontal layout with text,

but my application and scrolling is now a few laggy and it is for layouts and they are much!

but i need them, what should i do??

```
public class CardAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CardAdapter.ViewHolder> {

//Imageloader to load image
private ImageLoader imageLoader;
private Context context;

//List to store all superheroes
List<Getter_Setter> superHeroes;

//Constructor of this class
public CardAdapter(List<Getter_Setter> superHeroes, Context context){
    super();
    //Getting all superheroes
    this.superHeroes = superHeroes;
    this.context = context;
}




@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.ads_list, parent, false);
    ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(v);
    return viewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    //Getting the particular item from the list
    Getter_Setter superHero =  superHeroes.get(position);

    //Loading image from url
    imageLoader = CustomVolleyRequest.getInstance(context).getImageLoader();
    imageLoader.get(superHero.getImageUrl(), ImageLoader.getImageListener(holder.imageView, R.drawable.imageloader, android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert));

    //Showing data on the views
    holder.imageView.setImageUrl(superHero.getImageUrl(), imageLoader);
    holder.textViewName.setText(superHero.getName());
    holder.textView_MainBrand.setText(superHero.getBrand());

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return superHeroes.size();
}

class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    //Views
    public NetworkImageView imageView;
    public TextView textViewName;
    public TextView textView_MainBrand;

    //Initializing Views
    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        imageView = (NetworkImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageViewHero);
        textViewName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewName);
        textView_MainBrand = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView_MainBrand);
    }
}
```

}

[My Applicatoin Picture...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X6rz4.jpg)

Comment: Try Picasso for loading images.

Comment: But its not for my images , when i delete images completely , its still laggy

Comment: Use method tracing to determine where you are spending your time.

Comment: Your app picture shows that there's a lot going on with OnClickListeners, Images, setText, findViews, and probably more.

Laggy almost always means there's too much happening. EVERYTIME you scroll ALL THAT CODE has to run.

Minimize the code, cache images, put as much code outside the recycler as possible.